# Oracle sql split up rows according to max value in column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a select result like this:

```
 ID  |  Amount    
---------------
 xx1 |  105
 xx2 |  70
```

I would like to split up the row into multiple rows if the amount is greater than 50 resulting in:

```
 ID  |  Amount
---------------
 xx1 |  50
 xx1 |  50
 xx1 |  5
 xx2 |  50
 xx2 |  20
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A recursive solution:

```
WITH t(id, amount) AS
  (SELECT id, amount
   FROM mytable
   UNION ALL
   SELECT id, amount - 50
   FROM t
   WHERE amount - 50 > 0)
SELECT id
      ,least(amount, 50) amount
FROM t
ORDER BY id
        ,least(amount, 50) DESC
```

Following Frank Schmitt's comment. A `MODEL` solution which should work in Oracle 10g:

```
SELECT id
     , least(amt, 50) amount
FROM
  (SELECT id
        , amt
   FROM mytable t
   MODEL
     PARTITION BY (id)
     DIMENSION BY (0 d)
     MEASURES (amount amt)
     RULES ITERATE (1024) UNTIL (amt[ITERATION_NUMBER] < 50)
       ( amt[ITERATION_NUMBER+1] = amt[ITERATION_NUMBER] - 50 ))
WHERE amt > 0
ORDER BY id
       , amt DESC
```

You should ensure that 1024*50 >= max(amount), or change the maximum number of iterations to perform appropriately.

Comment: +1 Nice. It might be worth noting that recursive CTE's don't work in older versions of Oracle, though (AFAIK, they were added in 11gR2).